# Using Jest to mock a React component with props

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component which contains some other components that depend on access to a Redux store etc., which cause issues when doing a full Enzyme mount. Let's say a structure like this:

```js
import ComponentToMock from './ComponentToMock';

<ComponentToTest>
  ...some stuff
  <ComponentToMock testProp="This throws a warning" />
</ComponentToTest>
```

I want to use Jest's `.mock()` method to mock out the sub-component, so that it is not a concern for the test.

I'm aware that I can mock out a straight component with something like:

`jest.mock('./ComponentToMock', () => 'ComponentToMock');`

However, as this component would normally receive props, React gets upset, giving a warning about unknown props (in this case, `testProp`) being passed to `<ComponentToMock />`.

I've tried to return a function instead, however you can't return JSX (from what I could tell) in a Jest mock, due to it being hoisted. It throws an error in this case.

So my question is how can I either

a) get `ComponentToMock` to ignore props passed to it, or

b) return a React component that can be used to mock the child component that I'm not worried about testing.

Or... is there a better way?

Comment: I just had a lot of trouble with this myself, but it was answered here: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080332/2884555)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a note at the bottom of the [docs for `jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) for preventing the hoisting behavior:

> Note: When using `babel-jest`, calls to `mock` will automatically be
>   hoisted to the top of the code block. Use `doMock` if you want to
>   explicitly avoid this behavior.

Then you can do as you described: return a function that is a stub of the component you don't need to test.

```js
jest.doMock('./ComponentToMock', () => {
  const ComponentToMock = () => <div />;
  return ComponentToMock;
});

const ComponentToTest = require('./ComponentToTest').default;
```

It's helpful to name the stub component since it gets rendered in snapshots.

Comment: This is good to know! The docs mention it a little off-handedly. However, I tried this and it still didn't work out. Because the import of <ComponentToMock /> happens when the <ComponentToTest /> is brought in, unless Jest's mock is hoisted to be first, it happens after the fact and the mock does not work.

Comment: I updated the snippet: you have to do the mocking and then require the component to test.

Comment: I've managed to get this working in a basic sense. It does require the use of... require, ahem, not import. That may be worth considering for anyone with a similar situation. I've got a more complex setup that seems to not be working with the fix, but that could just be some interfering HOCs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same here, this solution does not work out, it throws a `Invariant Violation: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument.` Seems that we should live with the warnings upon test output.

Comment: Depending on the way your component is exported/imported you might need to do `return {ComponentToMock}`

Answer (score 32):

I've learned a little more since I asked this question. Here's an alternative (better?) way of dealing with mocking components that need to be passed props: using module *mock files*.

First create a file with the same name as the component to mock in a `__mocks__` folder under the component's folder e.g.

```js
.
|- /ComponentToMock.js
└- /__mocks__/ComponentToMock.js <-- create this folder/file!
```

*Note*: It seems as of the time of writing, the folder *must* be called `__mocks__` (you will need to create `__mocks__` in each folder you need to mock components for. If the underscores upset you, just pretend they aren't there ;) )

Next, in this mock file, you can write the file as you wish, e.g.

```js
// This code would live in ./__mocks__/ComponentToMock.js
import React from 'react';
const ComponentToMock = ({ testProp }) => <div>A mock with '{testProp}' passed!</div>;
export default ComponentToMock;
```

Then in the test file, change the Jest mock statement to:

```js
jest.mock('./ComponentToMock');
```

When Jest encounters a `.mock()` without the second function parameter, it automatically looks for a `__mocks__` folder. However, even though the mock statement gets hoisted in the component being tested, this doesn't affect the imports of the mock itself - hence why it's able to import and compile a React component!

This seems to work well for mocked components that need to be passed props, and would otherwise produce prop warnings if a nulled function was returned (but which is perfectly acceptable to continue using if the component does not receive props). I hope this helps some people out there.

Comment: The part about pretending not to see the underscores was very helpful. I will!

Comment: Just wanna add that `jest.mock('./ComponentToMock');` needs to be at the same level as the imports (before `describe`). Took me some minutes to figure that out, I hope to save someone else's time

Answer (score 5):

Addition to accepted answer, If you are using multiple exports then mocking can be done as follows:

```js
// Component.jsx

export { A, B };
```

```js
// Component-test.js

jest.mock("../src/Component", () => {
  return {
    A: true,
    B: () => {
      return <></>;
    },
  };
})
```

Reference Blog: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mocking-react-components-with-jest

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was unable to make the mock work.

An it turned out to be case-sensitivity issue:

Module Filename: `Autosuggest.js`

How i was mocking it: `jest.mock('./AutoSuggest', ...);`   <-- wrong cases

Answer (score 0):

Jest Recommended and works perfect for me for a default export component

https://jestjs.io/docs/next/tutorial-react

`jest.mock('../SomeDirectory/SomeComponent', () => 'SomeComponent');`

Answer (score -1):

```
const mockComponent = ComponentName => ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <ComponentName {...{ '[mockComponent]': true }} {...props}>
    {children}
  </ComponentName>
);

export default mockComponent;
```

```
jest.mock('../ComponentToMock', () => {
  const mockComponent = require('./mockComponent').default;

  return mockComponent('ComponentToMock');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone uses `Vitest` try this

```
vi.mock('path-to-component', () => {
  return {
    default: () => <div />, // your mock React component
  };
});
```